# MySQL limit across multiple tables in multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that keeps track of 'changes' that users make. These changes come in all shapes and sizes and each shape and size has a different MySQL table to store them in. In total there are 8 different tables. Each table has completely different columns, so I don't *think* a simple `JOIN` would be possible, however they all have a `time` column.

What I would like to do is show the last `x` number of changes made across all tables (i.e. sorted by `time`). How I am doing it now is querying all tables like this:

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT $table.*,
            realname,
            time,
            reservations.conf_num,
            reservations.conf_letters
        FROM
            $table
        LEFT JOIN users ON $table.user_id = users.id
        LEFT JOIN reservations
            ON $table.conf_num = reservations.conf_num
        ORDER BY
            time DESC
        LIMIT ".$this->_num_values);
    $stmt->execute();

    $changes[$table] = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Then I sort and slice the resultant array:

```
ksort($changes);
$changes = array_reverse($changes);

// Make sure to limit it if we have a maximum number of values
if ($this->_num_values > 0) {
    $changes = array_slice($changes, 0, $this->_num_values);
}
```

This works fine, however it just seems extremely inefficient to me since we are retrieving the latest `x` values from **all** tables instead of just returning the exact number so that the sum of the number of rows from the individual queries equals `x`. Is there a better way to do this, or am I just trying to micro-optimize too much here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: create a stored procedure and UNION the result sets then sort the records and return them to PHP.

Comment: Edit comment. I'm working on it. I'll keep you posted if I have any trouble working this out. I've never done `UNION` before.

Comment: It was complicated and took me 2-3 hours, but I finally have it working. Thanks for the suggestion.